# Super Hero Movie That's Not Spider-Man

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie on the Sci Fi Channel either the late '90s or early 2000s. A young man becomes a Spider-Man-like hero, but is more spider than man. He becomes more monster-like and dies at the end. The final shot is of someone grabbing an action figure of him.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think it's [Earth vs. the Spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_vs._the_Spider_(2001_film)).

**Either late 90's or early 2000's:**

> Earth vs. the Spider is a **2001 science fiction** horror television film directed by Scott Ziehl.

**A young man becomes a Spiderman-like hero, but is more spider than man:**

> Quentin Kemmer (Devon Gummersall) is a shy security guard and obsessive comic book fan who dreams of becoming a superhero like his favorite comic book character The Arachnid Avenger, and going out with his next-door neighbor Stephanie Lewis (Amelia Heinle). When his partner is killed during a botched robbery at the research laboratory where he works, Quentin is fired and he **injects himself with an experimental serum derived from spiders**. The next day he is wracked with a severely high fever and spends most of the day unconscious. After he recovers he discovers that he has developed increased strength.

**The final shot is of someone grabbing an action figure of him:**

> The film ends with Quentin's friend Han, introduce a comic book collector to an **action figure** that resembles his friend, now a superhero named Quentin Arachnid.